# How to reassign value to struct inside map (Golang)

Tags: csv, go, parsing

I am parsing a police records csv file. There are multiple occurrences of the same date in the file. I have the dates map that creates a new date key with the type of DateData assigned to it.
The DateDate for now only has a `Count` key. That key is to be incremented every time the same date appears again in the loop. Right now I am only able to increment once. the count goes from 1 to 2 even if there are dozens of the same dates.

This is the output I get with a shorter version of the csv file for clarity purposes.

```
user@MacBook-Pro-3 criminal-record-parser % go run main.go
Does not exist yet
{1}
{2}
{2}
{2}
{2}
```

The count shoud be increasing to total up to 5, but It only increases one time
Here is all my code in the main package:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

type Report struct {
    Date      string `json:"date"`
    Address   string `json:"address"`
    District  string `json:"district"`
    Beat      string `json:"beat"`
    Grid      string `json:"grid"`
    Crimedesc string `json:"crimedesc"`
    UCRCode   string `json:"ucr_ncic_code"`
    Lat       string `json:"latitude"`
    Lon       string `json:"longitude"`
}

type DateData struct {
    Count int
}

func main() {

    reports := CreateReport()

    var dates = make(map[string]DateData)

    for _, report := range reports {

        dateIndex := strings.LastIndex(report.Date, "/")
        date := report.Date[0 : dateIndex+3]

        val, ok := dates[date]
        if !ok {
            fmt.Println("Does not exist yet")
            dates[date] = DateData{
                Count: 1,
            }

        }

        val.Count += 1
        fmt.Println(val)

    }

    fmt.Println("dates slice", dates)

}

func CreateReport() []Report {
    csvFile, err := os.Open("./files/sacramento-test.csv")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("error opeining file", err)
    }

    defer csvFile.Close()

    reader := csv.NewReader(csvFile)
    var reports []Report

    for {
        line, err := reader.Read()
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        } else if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("error reading file", err)
        }

        reports = append(reports, Report{
            Date:      line[0],
            Address:   line[1],
            District:  line[2],
            Beat:      line[3],
            Grid:      line[4],
            Crimedesc: line[5],
            UCRCode:   line[6],
            Lat:       line[7],
            Lon:       line[8],
        })

    }

    return reports
}
```

Why is my Count value for the DateData struct only increasing once. What is another way to change values

When I try to change the Count value this way: `dates[date].Count += 1` 
I get this error:

```
cannot assign to struct field dates[date].Count in mapcompilerUnaddressableFieldAssign
```

The CSV file it is parsing

```
1/1/06 0:00,3108 OCCIDENTAL DR,3,3C        ,1115,10851(A)VC TAKE VEH W/O OWNER,2404,38.55042047,-121.3914158
1/1/06 0:00,2082 EXPEDITION WAY,5,5A        ,1512,459 PC  BURGLARY RESIDENCE,2204,38.47350069,-121.4901858
1/1/06 0:00,4 PALEN CT,2,2A        ,212,10851(A)VC TAKE VEH W/O OWNER,2404,38.65784584,-121.4621009
1/1/06 0:00,22 BECKFORD CT,6,6C        ,1443,476 PC PASS FICTICIOUS CHECK,2501,38.50677377,-121.4269508
1/1/06 0:00,3421 AUBURN BLVD,2,2A        ,508,459 PC  BURGLARY-UNSPECIFIED,2299,38.6374478,-121.3846125
```

Comment: Not directly answering your question, but why do you need a struct type with only one field for keeping count? Why not just use a `map[string]int` type in your `main()` function for keeping count?

Comment: You're updating a copy of the count - but not assigning back to the map.

Comment: @jidicula I am eventually going to add more fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not updating your `map` with the updated count. Add:

```
val.Count += 1
fmt.Println(val)

dates[date] = val // <--- add this
```

https://play.golang.org/p/jwDgDGDnXAw

Output:

```
Does not exist yet
{1}
{2}
{3}
{4}
{5}
dates slice map[1/1/06:{5}]
```